# How to stop all threads in the tree?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

If I execute ExecutorService.shutdownNow() in Main thread  it does not stop all threads but If I execute ExecutorService.shutdownNow() in Thread1 or Thread2 it kills its sub child threads
How to cascade shutdown command to the lowest level?

```
       Main thread
        /      \
       /        \
Thread 1   Thread 2
|   |  |     |  |    
A   B  C     D   E
```

How to kill all threads from main thread?

using below snippet to craete thread

```
CompletionService<Object> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<Object>(threadExecutor);
                        List<Future<Object>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<Object>>();
                        for(MultiThread mt : threadList)
                        {
                         futures.add(completionService.submit(mt));
                        }

                        while (futures.size() > 0) {
                            Future f = completionService.take();
                            futures.remove(f);
                            try {
                              Object result = f.get();
                              System.out.println(result); 
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                              System.out.println("Caught exception from one task: " + e.getCause().getMessage() + ". shutdown now!");
                              threadExecutor.shutdownNow();
                              break;
                            }
                        }
```

How to handle interruption in child thread?

Comment: How many `Executor`s do you have? Have you called the instance method `shutdownNow()` on all of them?

Comment: I have 2 executors ...1 in main thread and the other in its child thread which creates thread1 and thread 2..I have called shutdownNow() on both executor but I guess only thread1 and thread2 executors shutdownNow() is working

Comment: From my experience with multi-threading you have to loop over each thread and set it to null or terminate it however you're doing it now.  I normally like to create my threads by implementing Runnable.

Comment: Threads can only be stopped if they cooperate. And if they spawn child threads they also have to take care about them.

Comment: To expand on zapl’s point: There is no such thing as “stopping a thread.”  `shutdownNow` just interrupts each thread.  It is up to the author of each Runnable and Callable to properly respond to an interrupt by exiting cleanly.

Comment: Executors are not "in" a thread.

Answer (score 1):

shutdownNow
List shutdownNow()
Based on Javadoc:
Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution. 
This method does not wait for actively executing tasks to terminate. Use awaitTermination to do that.

There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. **For example, typical implementations will cancel via Thread.interrupt(), so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.**

Comment: Possible that your running task does not Yield and does not response to an Interrupt event.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ThreadPoolExecutor and pass an instance of a ThreadFactory.  The ThreadFactory will use a unique ThreadGroup that is associated with each new thread that is created.  If you need to interrupt all of the threads then you can just use the ThreadGroup interrupt method and all of the threads will be interrupted.

```
public class GroupThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private ThreadGroup group;

    public GroupThreadFactory(ThreadGroup group) {
         this.group = group;
    }

    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
         return new Thread(group, r);
    }
}
```